# Get Service type from C++

Tags: ros, c++, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this code there is a function to get the type of a Service "get_service_type()": http://ros-win32.servicerobotics.eu/trunk/cturtle/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py
How can I do that from C++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152481/get-service-type-from-c++/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-13**:
What are you trying to achieve with this? Are you just trying to get the name of the service type, or will you try to call it after you've retrieved the type?

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-13**:
I want to create a Parameter with the information of each Service. Name, Type, Request and Response. To be able to call a service from another computer with rosbridge without having to look at the service from Ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the functionality you're looking for is already implemented as a service in the [rosapi package](http://wiki.ros.org/rosapi) and it can be accessed natively from roslibjs via the [getServices](http://robotwebtools.org/jsdoc/roslibjs/current/ROSLIB.Ros.html#getServices) method.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1